# Lottery - Probability vs. Anomaly

Tags: probability

The Background:

To keep things fair, my league does a lottery drawing for the weakest teams. Currently we use a ball drawing system (4 balls awarded to the last place team, 3 balls for the next worst, 2 balls for the next, and 1 ball for the next ). We have done the lottery for 6 years, and not once has the worst team been drawn first.

Here's the question:

Would we reduce the chance for anomaly by increasing the total balls? (100 total balls, 40-30-20-10).

Comment: On the first pick, there will be no difference in the probability for the worst team.